# NestJs Angular Universal ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined

Tags: angular, nestjs, angular-universal

Please assist, i have an application using angular universal (angular 8 and NestJs). i am trying to access session storage inside an angular component(`onInit`) but NestJs is giving me the following : `ERROR ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined`. After looking at [angular DI](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#supply-a-custom-provider-with-inject) I then tried the following :

```
export const BROWSER_STORAGE  = new InjectionToken<Storage>('Browser Storage', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => window.sessionStorage
});
```

Then in my component:

```
 constructor(@Inject(BROWSER_STORAGE) public storage: Storage) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.storage.setItem('store', 'store');
  }
```

Now getting the following error `ERROR TypeError: this.storage.setItem is not a function`. How can i set/get session storage data using angular universal (angular 8 and NestJs).

Comment: Are you using `sessionStorage` or is it one of your 3r party lib?

Comment: @David updated the question,  an using ```sessionStorage``` built in DOM method.

Comment: You cannot use  native`sessionStorage` server side (universal). You need to either provide a mock, or not call your service if the code is executing server side (using isPlatformBrowser for instance)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to David. To make NestJs not to execute `this.storage.setItem('store', 'store');` had to inject `PLATFORM_ID` and use `isPlatformBrowser` as follows :

```
  constructor(
    @Inject(BROWSER_STORAGE) public storage: Storage,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) public platformId: object
  ) {}
```

Then inside ngInit:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('store', 'store');
      this.storage.setItem('storeDI', 'storeDI');
    }
  }
```

`isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)` will return `false` on the server side and `true`  on the browser side.